# Visual studio skip changes in code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I had a `ASP.NET MVC` project. I changed some lines.
But Visual Studio refuses to add changes. Every time I run my code old code is deployed.
In source file I have:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.Label("Device name: ", new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
            @Html.TextBox("deviceName", null, new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this code in browser:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon" for="Manufacturer:_">Manufacturer: </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="deviceManufacturer" name="deviceManufacturer" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

As You can see it's rendered as old code. I changed Manufacturer to Device name.
I tried:

- Closing  and reopening solution
- Clean solution
- Rebuild

  With no effect. What else can I do?

Comment: If by "this code in browser", you mean looking source code inside your browser, it would be pretty strange to receive anything else but HTML and CSS... So I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Are you sure you are making the change to the same file ?

Comment: @Kilazur In browsers its renders as label and input for `Manufacturer` instead of `device name` (this was the change in code). @Yasser, I'm sure that I edit same file

Comment: @szpic Oh, ok, I've read too fast, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is a problem with file caching. There are 2 possible reasons:

1. Your browser caches the data. You can try to clear your browser cache. Google can tell you how.
2. VS itself caches the data. There are 2 folders you need to delete to fix this:

   ```
   %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
   %Temp%\VWDWebCache
   ```

Comment: Does the same apply for vb.net winforms?

Comment: Winforms can also have problems with caching. There is another folder somewhere in appdata that stores these. Not sure where though.

Comment: I managed to fix this by cleaning the solution then rebuilding it

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the project folder, right click on it click on properties, there is an option "Attributes" Read Only, i guess that might be Checked, please uncheck that, click Apply, then save the file on visual studio and try checking it,

I am not sure how much help it can do for you, but i faced this problem, it was not saving the code, since Read only is checked, so I fixed based on this